# netbeans-like performance hints in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-hinting

So I'm recently forced to use netbeans after using eclipse for years now while I never considered netbeans as a real alternative. But now I happened to find a cute feature in netbeans I haven't seen in eclipse so far: `Java Performance Code Hints`. Netbeans complains about things like "pointless binary operations (0 | 4)", "manually copying lists" or "creating new `Boolean` is inefficient".

Does anybody know if I can get those in eclipse too? I don't think eclipse comes with such a feature built-in. But I hope there's a plugin. Currently at work so I can't use eclipse market place to search. Google didn't give me much.

Comment: You've got PMD, FindBugs, and CheckStyle.

Comment: NB 7.2 has enormous features. I like "Assign Return Value To New Variable". You can find everything under Options->Editor->Hints.

Comment: vels4j Maybe, but that was not the question.
Laf and Marko Topolnik, thanks. I think this is just what I was looking for. Will test some of them soon.